# $date_gmt nginx Windows кириллица

Tags: nginx, время, config, php-nginx

Всем привет!

Использую nginx + php-fastcgi на Windows 10, к сожалению, так и не нашёл способ форматировать время на уровне конфигурационного файла.

Насколько я понял, время, в основном, получают из глобальной переменной `$date_gmt`, в документации также нашёл переменные `$time_local` и `$time_iso8601`, однако их формат мне не подходит. При этом переменная `$date_gmt` содержит, как я понял, значение в системном формате, в моём случае это кириллический вариант, то есть, она возвращает всегда название дня и месяца на русском, например: `суббота, 18-май-2019 01_57_49 RTZ 1 (зима)`. И если, допустим, использовать переменную `$date_gmt` в заголовках, то в браузере значение будет некорректно отображаться:
`Last-Modified: �������, 18-���-2019 02:08:17 RTZ 1 (����)`

Есть ли возможность использовать другие форматы для получения текущего времени в конфиге nginx.conf?

Comment: Эээ? А зачем формировать эти заголовки в nginx? Отправьте их из php.

Comment: @AlexeyTen это да, понятно, но меня немного смущает отсутствие самой возможности форматировать эти заголовки на уровне сервера :)

Comment: Видимо никому это не нужно, что логично. Last-modified имеет смысл для файлов и для них он ставится автоматически. Обычно людям нужен Expires и для него есть соответствующая директива. Впрочем сейчас вам никто не мешает на lua/ngscript создать любой заголовок

Comment: @Alexey Ten да, верно. Спасибо!